# includeFontPadding doesn't works in API 21

Tags: android, layout, fonts, textview

I'm using the `includeFontPadding = false` to remove the font spacing in my `TextView`'s and in Android 28(Right) works fine but in Android 21(Left) still with the font padding in the top.

I was checking in the android developers [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setIncludeFontPadding(boolean)) and the `setIncludeFontPadding` was introduced in API 1.

[image]

Do you have an idea what's happening?